# Does the FAA allow a BFR endorsement without a medical?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa

I am told by a CFI that he can give a BFR but can’t endorse the logbook of someone who does not have a current medical certificate. Do FAA regulations allow a BFR endorsement for someone without medical?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Any CFI, who holds a current flight instructor certificate in the appropriate aircraft category and class can give you a flight review and sign off your logbook. That being said, you may not exercise your privileges as pilot in command without a current medical certificate or BasicMed under the conditions specified under §61.23.

Comment: Your answer should be YES. Exercising the privileges of your pilot certificate requires you to have a current medical, but flying with an instructor does not require a medical or even a certificate for that matter.

Comment: That’s not the issue. The question was whether you had to hold a valid medical in order to have a CFI sign off a flight review in your logbook, which is not required.

Comment: The question has been edited so “no“ may have been the answer to the original question. But as currently written, the answer is “yes”; a CFI can sign off on a BFR for someone without a current medical.

Comment: It’s edited. Hopefully that makes everybody happy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such rule. If the CFI themselves does not have a medical or proper endorsements or is otherwise unable to act as pilot in command of the aircraft the flight review will be done in, they might not be able to do the flight portion of the flight review. For instance, a CFI without a tailwheel endorsement is allowed to give a flight review even in a tailwheel aircraft, but since they can not act as PIC, you would need to do so. Which means having a current flight review and a medical. But they can certainly endorse it if it has been done.

Glider/sport/etc pilots don't even require a medical to fly. How does this CFI imagine they get their flight reviews?

Answer (score 1):

Considered narrowly, the CFI’s statement that you relayed is incorrect. [FAR 61.56](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.56), “Flight review,” does not mention the medical certificate at all, nor does [61.189](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-H/section-61.189) (“Flight instructor records”).

Most of the time, “a flight review consists of a minimum of 1 hour of flight training and 1 hour of ground training.” In the case of a pilot who does not have a current flight review and a CFI unwilling to act as pilot in command, they would not be able to complete the flight portion of the flight review, and thus the CFI could not endorse the pilot’s logbook as having “satisfactorily completed the review.”